# Can a PC mouse cause short circuit in my pc?

Tags: usb, soldering, troubleshooting

My rabbit chewed on my pc mouse and I had it fixed (soldered) because the mouse is no longer for sale and I am fond of the product. It seems to work just fine. About 6-8 months after this happened, I got PC issues that caused my USB devices (everything you plug in, in both 2.0 and 3.0, in any port.) to randomly connect and disconnect. I've tried to replace the mouse/keyboard, replaced the motherboard, upgraded the OS and all drivers.

Replacing the motherboard worked for about 2 months, now the problem has returned. However, I have also been using the soldered mouse for those 2 months.

**Is it possible that my soldered mouse is causing a short circuit in my pc, possibly messing with my motherboard?**

Comment: Of course it can. Shorting USB power can kill your computer (or a part of it).

Comment: Is it *possible* - certainly. Is this the actual cause of your problems - no-one here could possibly know...

Comment: @brhans if it is a possibility I can try *another* motherboard in combination with a new mouse and see if it holds up or not. I am currently out of solutions to try and desperate.

Comment: But you have replaced the mouse, right? So why would you suspect it? I would suspect the components which are remained the same..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have replaced the mouse for a day or 2. This didn't 'fix' the issue so I went back to using the mouse I like best, which is the soldered one.

Comment: Then it is impossible to tell from our position..

Comment: @EugeneSh. well you already gave me the answer I was looking for, if it was a possibility or not. So thank you, I have something else I can try.

Comment: Officially, USB should be short-circuit-proof, but actual implementations vary.

Comment: Well - [for science](https://xkcd.com/242/) - you could try another motherboard with the same old suspect mouse and see what happens - if this one dies too then the likelihood of the mouse being the culprit is increased ...

Comment: Pet spit can also corrode the metals in the cable and the plug.  This can cause a high resistance and/or intermittent contact.  This could cause the PC to think the mouse has dropped and reconnected; if it happens fast enough other devices on the same hub could be affected.  Really putting the plug in and out a couple of times can clean the contacts.

Answer (score 4):

A properly built USB port should have a load switch with a circuit breaker.  A shorted USB power will cause excessive current, which will trip (open) the breaker.  That should prevent damage to the PC.  Once the short is removed, the breaker will close, and the USB port can be used again.

(Having said that, there are plenty of <strike>cost-optimized</strike>  cheap USB hubs without load switches. [Case in point.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75654/7-port-powered-usb-hub-backfeeding-to-my-pc))

Comment: To complete your point, I think it is ok (in regards to the USB spec) for a hub to not include load switch, but it isn't ok for a host port not to be protected in some way. To be confirmed, though.